# Inject Javascript Code along With HTML in MVC HTML Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, model-view-controller, html-helper

I want to create a HTML Helper For a button and I want to inject some javascript(jQuery) code with that button to my page. How I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to build script tag using HTML Helper?

Comment: @DanNguyen : I want to create HTML Helper for `DropDownList` and use it in scenario with cascade `DropDownList`

Comment: maybe you want to update your question. it said that you want yo create a button using MVC HTML Helper

Comment: @Arian use knockout and create a client side view model and bind it to the drop down lists. Should then be able to preform cascading drop down list as desired.

Comment: @Arian provide a [mcve] of the desired output. this would allow for better suggestions to achieve what you require.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you add a script in your htmlHelper?
(of course you can add the scripts as parameters)

```
public static class MyHtmlHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyButton(this HtmlHelper helper,string text)
    {
        string script = @"<script> function MyMethod(){ alert('You clicked the button') ;} </script> ";
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.AppendLine(script);
        html.AppendLine("<input type = 'submit' value = '"+ text + "' onclick='MyMethod()'");
        html.Append("/>");
        return new MvcHtmlString(html.ToString());
    }
}
```

and in your view

```
@Html.MyButton("Click Me")
```

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion is to set Id of button using Id in input tag and add JQuery/Javascript code in @scripts section. This can be done with html or using helper like this

```
 <input id="btnClick" type="button" value="Click Me!">
```

or using HtmlHelper:

```
 public enum ButtonType { button = 0, submit = 1, reset = 2 }

 public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
 {
    public static MvcHtmlString Button(this HtmlHelper helper, ButtonType type, string textValue, string id)
    {
               string buttonTagText = $"<input type=\"{type.ToString()}\" value=\"{textValue}\" id = \"{id}\" />";
               return MvcHtmlString.Create(buttonTagText);
    }
 }
```

In View file (in case extension is used)

```
 @Html.Button(ButtonType.button, "Click Me!", "btnClick")
```

Then add script as below:

```
@section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~Scripts/buttonScript.js")
}
```

or add inline JS within section or refer bundled JS. In this way, JS logic can be separated from html tag, would help in getting intellisense support and easy to maintain/test code.
Within Script button reference can be retrieved using

```
var myButton = $("#btnClick");
```

Then this reference can be used for desired script logic.

Also, ensure the script section is added in _layout.cshtml as below:

```
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: I would suggest using a data attribute, if applicable, compared to an Id, as an attribute could be more re-usable. However, this pattern observes progressive enhancement, so this is the better way to go (as opposed to inlining the script).

Answer (score -1):

Add  the below line in your view page

```
 @Html.Button("Click Me!", htmlAttributes:new {Onclick="OnClickfunction"})
```

then add the following in your script section

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function OnClickfunction()
   {
   //Write Your Code here while click.....
   }
   </script>
```